# Group of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{-1,1\}$?

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Hope you're all having a wonderful day. I just came across the following statement:

"...*consider only convolution on **the group $G = \{−1, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$**
provided with its Haar measure λ.*"

How is G a group? I can't see how to make it work. Here is the article http://michel.talagrand.net/prizes/convolution.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f,g\in\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, let $f\cdot g=fg$. Note that if $f(n),g(n)\in \{-1,1\}$, then so is $f(n)g(n)$ so $f\cdot g\in  \{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The identity is the function $f$ such that $f(n)=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f=f^{-1}$ for all $f\in \{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

I trust you're familiar enough with groups to verify that everything works out.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to make it work with function composition.